# Controlling bits in a ushort array

Tags: c#, bit

I would like to know how I can read and write specific bits efficiently to a ushort integer.

The methods would be something like so:

```
// Sets the bit positioned at bitNumber in the ushort integer b
// to be either 1 or 0 depending on state.
public ushort SetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber, bool state)
{
   ushort result = b;
   // Code to set the specific bit in ushort result.
   return result
}
// Returns the value of the bit in position bitNumber from the 
// ushort b as a true or false.
public bool GetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber)
{
   bool stateOfBit = false;
   // Code to read the bit into stateOfBit.
   return stateOfBit;
}
```

I have tried using BitArray class but it only takes a byte or a 32 bit integer.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that your `SetBit` will have to return the updated `ushort` value, or you have to add the `ref` keyword before the parameter.  I would recommend the former over the latter.

Comment: Yes of course. :)
Thanks for that. I will update my question.

Comment: Do you want `bitNumber` to be zero or one based?  That is do you want the least significant or first bit to be `bitNumber` zero or one?  Also you are going from least significant to most right?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're trying to use this method to set specific 'flags' you would be better off with an enum with the `[Flags]` attribute.  However, this is just useless information if that's not your endgame.

Comment: Also to add on to @juharr 's comment you might be better off making this an object that just contains a `private ushort` variable so you don't need to keep passing references around.

Comment: Take a look at [`BitVector32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx) It has ways to only access / set / manipulate the first 16 bits, which sounds like what you're looking for.  Just keep in mind that it's a struct and therefore a valuetype. However, you can wrap it in a custom class and then you can add methods and even prevent access to the front 16 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ushort s = 0;
//set the 5th bit from the right to true
s |= 1 << 5;
//set the 5th bit from the right to false
//~ will return a negative number, so casting to int is necessary
int i = s;
i &= ~(1 << 5);
s = (ushort)i;
```

To do this in a method, you can either have the method return it or pass the ushort by reference:

```
public void SetBit(ref ushort b, int bitNumber, bool state) {
    if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber > 15)
        //throw an Exception or return
    if (state) {
        b |= (ushort)(1 << bitNumber);
    } else {
        int i = b;
        i &= ~(1 << bitNumber);
        b = (ushort)i;
    }
}

public bool GetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber) {
    if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber > 15)
        //throw an Exception or just return false
    return (b & (1 << bitNumber)) > 0;
}
```

To count bitNumber from the left, you need `15 - bitNumber`

Comment: The method really should check that `bitNumber` is 0-15.  Also to count from the left you'd want `15 - bitNumber` since it's zero based.

Comment: @juharr You're right. I was just thinking about that.

Comment: This works fine :)
I had to cast the "b |= 1 << bitNumber;" So it became like this "b |= (ushort)(1 << bitNumber);"  but other than that it works fine.
I will try it out a bit and if I have no trouble with it then I will mark it as the correct answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sigmundur Funny, if you use the literal 5, the cast isn't necessary. Because bitNumber is an int, `1 << bitNumber` is also an int, so then you need the cast. I have updated that line.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to guard against invalid `bitNumber` values by making sure it is between 1 and 16.

Then for setting you either want to "OR" it with a mask that has that bit set to one (by left shifting 1 to the desired position) if `state` is true.  Otherwise you "AND" it with a mask where all the bits are 1 except the one you want to set to zero (accomplished by NOT-ing the other mask).

For determining if the bit is set just "AND" it to the first mask mentioned and compare to zero.

```
public static ushort SetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber, bool state)
{
    if(bitNumber < 1 || bitNumber > 16)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitNumber", "Must be 1 - 16");

    return state ? 
        (ushort)(b | (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) : 
        (ushort)(b & ~(1 << (bitNumber - 1)));
}

public static bool GetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber)
{
    if (bitNumber < 1 || bitNumber > 16)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitNumber", "Must be 1 - 16");

    return (b & (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) > 1;
}
```

This assumes that you want `bitNumber` to be one-based from the least significant bit, or right most bit. If you want zero-based just remove the `- 1` used after `bitNumber` in all the code and adjust the `if` statement accordingly.  To make this start from the most significant or left most bit then just subtract 16 from `bitNumber` instead of 1 for one-based, or subtract 15 for zero-based.

Comment: I am sure this works also but I will pick Dennis_E's answer as the correct one since he answered before and it works perfectly for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked [juharr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29301724/1531971) (it looks cleaner and has less variable creation), but it is not right.  The last check should be (`> 0`) not (`> 1`).

```
public static ushort SetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber, bool state)
{
    if(bitNumber < 1 || bitNumber > 16)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitNumber", "Must be 1 - 16");

    return state ? 
        (ushort)(b | (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) : 
        (ushort)(b & ~(1 << (bitNumber - 1)));
}

public static bool GetBit(ushort b, int bitNumber)
{
    if (bitNumber < 1 || bitNumber > 16)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitNumber", "Must be 1 - 16");

    return (b & (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) > 0;
}
```